# Why time.strptime("Sept. 30, 2014", "%b. %d, %Y") Not working

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to parse date in python. My code work with all other months except Sept

Here is my code

```
time.strptime("Sept. 30, 2014", "%b. %d, %Y")
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: time data 'Sept. 30, 2014' does not match format '%b. %d, %Y'
```

Comment: Did you try it with `"Sep. ..."` instead of `"Sept. ..."`?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: here's [an answer to the related question (it is in Russian, but you could look at the code)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419422/23044). Ask, if something is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The abbreviation for September is Sep, not Sept.

```
>>> datetime.strptime("Sep. 30, 2014", "%b. %d, %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 30, 0, 0)
```

[Here's the list of all abbreviated month names for the en_US local.](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Locale-0.46/lib/DateTime/Locale/en_US.pm#Months)

Comment: Agreed. Further, the `en_US` locale details are listed here: http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Locale-0.46/lib/DateTime/Locale/en_US.pm#Months

Comment: @CraigOtis Thanks, I was looking for that!

Comment: Thanks, but the data i'm parsing has September like this Sept. so how do I deal with it ? I could just replace sept. with Sep but is there elegant solution

Comment: @MujtabaAlboori There's no way to make `strptime` accept Sept, so you'll have to replace it.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: look at `import calendar; list(calendar.month_abbr)` for a list of known month abbr. (in the current locale)

Answer (score 1):

The use of "Sept" in place of "Sep" seems to be a common occurrence.  As suggested by @morgan-thrapp, you have to replace the former with the latter:

```
time.strptime("Sept. 30, 2014".upper().replace("SEPT", "SEP"), "%b. %d, %Y")
```

The use of `upper()` converts all lower-case characters to upper-case, so that the use of `replace` is more straightforward.