# Python datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to parse dates in the form of `"Sept 9, 2021"` using `datetime`
I was trying the following format:

`"%m %d, %y"` but it raises a ValueError while I'm trying to convert it

(i.e using `int(datetime.strptime("Sept 9, 2021","%m %d, %y").timestamp())`)

How can I tell which format am I supposed to use?

Thanks

Comment: You can use this https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime. For your usecase it should be "%b %-d, %Y"

Comment: If your string started with 'Sep' you could use %b however, I don't think there's a format specifier for 'Sept'. You may have to parse that yourself

Comment: yes @LancelotduLac is right. The problem is 4 character in your month's name, if it was 3 characters you could have used the formate ```"%b %d, %Y"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `strptime` there are different format code than usual.
You use `%b` to refer to a Three-digit string month, which means that you must use `Sep` instead of `Sept`, and you use `%Y` to convert a 4 digit year.

So the code would be like the following

```
int(datetime.datetime.strptime("Sep 9, 2021", "%b %d, %Y").timestamp())
# 1631138400
```

For more information see [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the key work for September is Sep (not Sept).
You can check this link for more details on that: [Python Date abbreviation](https://metacpan.org/release/DROLSKY/DateTime-Locale-0.46/view/lib/DateTime/Locale/en_US.pm#Months)

I advice you to use something similar to this snippet of code:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_s = "Sep 9, 2021" 
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_s.upper().replace("SEPT", "SEP"), '%b %d, %Y')
print(datetime_object)
```

You can also check this Stack thread that seem similar to your question:
[Date Handling in Python for Sept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991435/why-time-strptimesept-30-2014-b-d-y-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways how to get the timestamp from your string:

First solution is to use `dateparser` module from PyPi (`pip install dateparser`). This module can help you to get datetime object from any string which is similar to datetime string.

### Solution:

```
import dateparser
date_time_object = dateparser.parse("Sept 9, 2021").timestamp()
print(date_time_object)
Result: 1631127600.0
```

Another issue is that your string contains one unnecessary string in name of month so this solution is a bit wrong and won't help you but only for understanding, I will offer this:

### Solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_stamp = int(datetime.strptime("Sep 9, 2021","%b %d, %Y").timestamp())
print(time_stamp)
Result: 1631127600
```